# How to use cursors to navigate a collection of twitter data scraped using a twitter API call

Tags: c#, api, twitter

How can I use cursors to iterate though a twitter api call?  I'm trying to get the locations of my twitter followers using the `GET followers/list` API call. i have done all the authentication related things in my application.

This is what I have done so far

```
            var resource_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json";
            var cursor = "-1";
            var api_path = resource_url;

            do {
                var url_with_cursor = api_path + "&cursor=" + cursor; 

                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url_with_cursor);
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
                request.Method = "GET";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

                string result = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

                JObject j = JObject.Parse(result);                    
                cursor = j["next_cursor_str"].ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(cursor);

            }
            while ( cursor != "0" );
```

But when I run the above code, I get an exception saying "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." in the following line of my code:

```
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

That means, there's something wrong with the response.

I haven't seen a proper example anywhere on how to get twitter data using cursors to navigate collections, except in the [developer site](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/misc/cursoring).

Comment: `That means there's something wrong with the response.` - Yes, that's what an exception indicates.  So what is the exception?

Comment: oh, so sorry! i haven't put that! i'll edit the post. and the exception says "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized"

Comment: That means you didn't set up your OAuth token correctly.

Comment: i'm able to get the data of the first 20 followers and not of the others because i have to access the next set of 20 followers using the next_cursor or the next_cursor_str. But i'm not sure where to put that. Is it before making the request or after everything?

Comment: Why don't you update your question with the code you are actually using then, or better yet a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What is the `resource_url` and do you actually get data in your `TwitterData.txt` file?   (Which btw, will probably be overridden on every iteration.  Pretty sure that api call doesn't append text, but I might be wrong)

Comment: i'm really very sorry. i updated it again. twitterData.txt is not needed. sorry for putting that. and resource_url is now included in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter requires that you authenticate / authorize with the api before you are allowed to extract data.  You'll need to follow their documentation to get an OAuth token.

- https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth
- https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/247336/Twitter-OAuth-authentication-using-Net

Also, it might be easier to use a wrapper library instead of going to twitter directly.  Twitter lists several for .Net: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries

For example [tweetSharp](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp):

```
 using TweetSharp;

 // In v1.1, all API calls require authentication
 var service = new TwitterService(_consumerKey, _consumerSecret);
 service.AuthenticateWith(_accessToken, _accessTokenSecret);

 var tweets = service.ListTweetsOnHomeTimeline(
                      new ListTweetsOnHomeTimelineOptions());

 foreach (var tweet in tweets)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("{0} says '{1}'", tweet.User.ScreenName, tweet.Text);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks again. I've already done the authentication things in my application. :) i'll try using a wrapper library. :)

Comment: do i have to download tweetsharp and include everything in it to my project? it  has a whole lot of things noh. :/

Comment: In general, it's usually easier to use a library that wraps the web calls to the social media APIs.  Doesn't take all of the hastle out of it, but it does help.